# Build Error: Cannot open include file: \TargetVersion\version.h, No such file or directory

Tags: c++, windows

I am getting a build error as "Cannot open include file: \TargetVersion\version.h, No such file or directory".

I am using the Visual Studio 2008 SP1 IDE, Windows 7 OS, Microsoft windows SDK 7.1.

Please suggest what I am missing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello and welcome! It might be worth having a look at [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) which has some tips on how to ask a great question that'll get you the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Lots of videos are in [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com) explaining  how to add library.